# negative lookahead regex still matching string

Tags: regex, regex-negation, regex-lookarounds

so I have this regex

```
(?!path1\/path2)
```

However this ends up matching the string 'path1/path2' properly even though I don't want any string that has path1/path2 to match

what did I do wrong?

https://regex101.com/r/mL3qM5/1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should anchor this lookahead with `^` and add `.*` to make sure we check the whole string that has no newline symbols:

```
^(?!.*path1\/path2)
```

The beginning of string anchor tells the regex engine to start looking for the pattern at the beginning *only*. In your regex, it was looking for that string at the first position, then the second, and it is there where it found a match.

Now, in plain words, `^(?!.*path1\/path2)` matches any string that does not contain `path1/path2`.

Comment: "I don't want any string that has `path1/path2` to match" - I read that to mean strings that don't *contain* `path1/path2`. Your regex is for strings that don't *start* with it.

Comment: Perhaps, I should stop answering questions at 1:00 AM :-D Updated.